# Trying to run Angular 4 without Node

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am .net/php/sql/JavaScript/Angular 1 developer, and I feel a bit lost regarding Angular 2/4 right now.

I am trying to run Angular 4 without Node.JS

1) I downloaded the QuickStart seed found on https://angular.io/guide/setup
( Direct link: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/archive/master.zip )

2) As recommended in [How to run AngularJS2 application without Node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398517/how-to-run-angularjs2-application-without-node-server)
I downloaded SystemJS from https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

3) Here my current html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="systemjs/system.js"></script>
    <script>
      SystemJS.import('test.js')
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

After line , I get

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

on line 1 of system.js which reads

```
import { global, isBrowser, isWorker } from './common.js';
```

How can I get through that error?

Comment: Why do you want to run Angular without Node.js? It is much easier to install Node.js, npm and the [Angular-CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), which is also recommended (see the [QuickStart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)).

Comment: Because I would like to run it on a shared hosting and I cannot install Node.js there.

Comment: You can try to use sfx version of Angular 2, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32226808). and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30100629/1578100)

Why not using require.js? I know quite old, but still worth if you need to support client browser rendering only.
I'm still using it with vue.js for some of my projects

Answer (score 3):

Try to create an app with angular-cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

```
ng new myApp
```

And then, build to static html

```
ng build --prod
```

You only need node in your development environment. With ng build your code is bundled and ready for any shared hosting